# How to set Unix epoch time (00:00:00)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is my code:

```
$(function () {
        function my_convert() {
      data = [{"Index":"\/Date(1449161293876)\/","Value":0},{"Index":"\/Date(1449247693876)\/","Value":0},{"Index":"\/Date(1449334093876)\/","Value":0},{"Index":"\/Date(1449349200000)\/","Value":5}]//data from server

                        var arr = []
                        data.forEach(function (i) {
                            var my_date = new Date(parseInt(i.Index.substr(6))).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)// setHours(3, 0, 0, 0)
                            arr.push([Number(my_date), i.Value])
                        })
                        return arr //[ [1449003600000,0], [1449090000000,21], [1449176400000,0]]
                    }
```

I tried to draw a graph (Highstock)
Why when i'm trying to set time "setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)" Im getting (21:00:00)?I had to set time like this "setHours(3, 0, 0, 0)" to get (00:00:00) WHY?

This is my code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Yura602/z0z7x4nt/4/

This is time converter (if you need): http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: I'm guessing your timezone is UTC-3? I think it's localizing to your timezone.

Comment: How about disabling `useUTC`? See: https://jsfiddle.net/z0z7x4nt/6/